# Combing two columns to form a Date in R using zoo

Tags: r, zoo

I am trying to use zoo to formulate a Date using two columns in a data.table.

data$Date <- as.yearmon(paste(data$Month,data$Year), "%Y %m")
But all I get in NA's

Here is what the data looks like:

```
Year    Month   State   County  Rate
2015    October California  Santa Clara County  4.0
2015    March   California  Santa Clara County  4.4
2015    August  California  Santa Clara County  4.1
2015    May California  Santa Clara County  4.1
2015    January California  Santa Clara County  4.7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two issues. One, you're pasting `Month`, `Year` but telling it you're sending `Year`, `Month`. In addition, `%m` is for month as a decimal 1-12. You want `%B` for full name of month. You need to switch the order of the paste and change the format.

```
data$Date <- as.yearmon(paste(data$Year,data$Month), "%Y %B")

   Year   Month      State             County Rate     Date
1: 2015 October California Santa Clara County  4.0 Oct 2015
2: 2015   March California Santa Clara County  4.4 Mar 2015
3: 2015  August California Santa Clara County  4.1 Aug 2015
4: 2015     May California Santa Clara County  4.1 May 2015
5: 2015 January California Santa Clara County  4.7 Jan 2015
```